# Sort a custom post type array numerically

Tags: array, sort, terms

We've set up drop down lists to allow people to filter posts based on custom post types.

In order to populate the drop down list I am using:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("ratios");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     echo "<option value='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</option>";
 }
}?>
</select>
```

The slug and the name are pretty similar, so I don't mind which one we are using.

How can I list them as integers?

The site is here if you need more of an idea: http://amigaeng.com.au/gearbox-list/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_terms` function will return an array of object. Each of them has `term_id` field which contains id of a term. Just use it instead of slug and you will have what you need:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("ratios");
if ( $count($terms) > 0 ){
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     echo "<option value='" . $term->term_id . "'>" . $term->name . "</option>";
 }
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene,
I think I must have missed a bit in my questions.
What I would actually like to know is how to then sort this array numerically?